# Let me double-click on the question expander to autosize it to the question

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, flag-queue

I have a flag in my site's queue:

[image]

I'd like to see the rest of the question (there's some backstory, he had a bad experience with pumpkins), and currently I would fumble around with the little divider thing until the question is fully in view.

It'd really be nice, though, if I could click, double-click, yell at, or otherwise invoke a feature to automatically make the question take up all the space it needs and no more.

My reasoning on this is that either I want to look at the question or I don't, there are generally very few use cases for seeing only the next sentence in a question.

Please eliminate the mental overhead required to move a slider thing up and down.

Edit: animuson points out that it might be better to burn the slidey bar thing and just have an expand/collapse button, which sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: *"...there are generally very few use cases for seeing only the next sentence in a question."* - I agree with that. Maybe it'd make more sense to not even have the slidey bar and just have an Expand/Collapse button. No double-clicking required. The only time I've ever used it to view just the next sentence is when there was only just another sentence to view.

Comment: I hate pumpkins. They're so... *orange*.

Comment: 9,552,189 comments! Those users had a lot to talk about pumpkins for sure.